# Why do we need binary trees when we have multi branch trees?

Tags: trees, binary-trees

Why do we need binary trees when we have multiway trees. Are binary trees even used. Are they used only for teaching the concepts of trees?

Comment: Depending on the context, a binary tree may be more useful than a tree with larger branching or vice versa. Unless you clarify a specific context to use the tree in, I think this question would be too broad.

Comment: You might as well ask why we need multiway trees when we have directed acyclic graphs, or indeed general digraphs. The most general data structure isn't always the most useful in a given situation.

Comment: @Discretelizard any situation where binary tree would be more useful than multiway tree?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, binary trees are used in standard libraries, implementing various data structures. For example, implementation of *ordered set* in the C++ STL library is typically based on [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which is a binary search tree of special kind.